# Google Pixel XL Messages app missing camera interface

Tags: applications, camera, user-interface, google-pixel

I reset my Google Pixel XL and temporally set it up as new device, meaning I did't restore any of the settings from before reset, therefore it is safe to assume I used all default settings.

During this time, I noticed the Messages app having a camera interface button next to the plus sign (see image) which when pressed, a small camera preview displayed allowing you to snap a quick picture.  I then reset the phone again, this time restoring old phone's data.  Now the above mentioned camera interface is gone and I don't know how to get it back.

Thanks,

[image]

Comment: Have you updated the app yet?

Comment: Yes, it is in it's latest version 3.9.039

Comment: After reset, system apps on your device switch to the version which you have seen on first boot. You need to update via play store to have latest features. And, yes latest version is the one you have mentioned. I have that on my device. Please backup messages(super backup and restore), and try to clear all data, and check again. (As it was a pixel device, I think it may have google drive backup of messages app by default, which is not available for other devices )